# Android - Simple repeating background task

Tags: android, repeat, background-service

I am trying to run simple background service, that will be every some period of time checking date ane doing what I want, but I have problems with creation. I was looging via uncle Google, but he coundn't help me. I don't have any code in spite of AndroidManifest.xml line: `<service android:name=".HelloService" />` and `public class HelloService extends Service { }`. How am I to write it? I don't want to use Alarms.

Comment: I don't have any code in spite of AndroidManifest.xml line: ? what does that mean ?

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) to run indefinitely, like with a `while` loop. Inside that loop you can use something like `Thread.sleep()` to make your `Service` way for a while. Or you could also use [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), depending on what you want to achieve.

Dunno why you don't want to use alarms, but that should also do the job.

More on `Handler` [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html).

---

**EDIT:** Sample code using `Handler`:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity { 

    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // The method you want to call every now and then.
            yourMethod();
            handler.postDelayed(this,2000); // 2000 = 2 seconds. This time is in millis.
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_slider);

        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000); // Call the handler for the first time.

    }

    private void yourMethod() { 
        // ... 
    } 
    // ...
}
```

**P.S.:** With this solution, your code will stop after the `Activity` is destroyed.